# Comparison of organic and inorganic acid strengths

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

So I know how different factors affect acid/base strength, but I am not sure when they are all in the same question, which affects acid/base strength more.

So, for example this question: [image]

How do I know that $\ce{HBr}$ is the strongest acid...because I also have the inductive electron withdrawal from Fluorine in answer choice B.

Answer (score 1):

pKa value is great indicator of acid base strength, lower the pKa value stronger is tha acid and conjugate base of that acid is week base due to high pKa value.

HBr has pKa value (-9) strongest acid after HI (pKa -10).